# Чем заменить if-else/switch-case при генерации объекта-наследника?

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток.

Имею БД СТО и программу которая с ней работает. Среди классов, отражающих сущности БД есть `Car`, который имеет несколько наследников: `LuxuryCar`, `SportCar` и т.д, а также поле типа `CarType`, отражающее какому типу машины относится данный экземпляр `Car`. При обращении к БД через Entity Framework я хочу получать список машин определенного `CarType`, сейчас это реализовано с использованием `if-else`, но я уверен, есть решение, которое позволит избавиться от `if-else` или `switch-case`

Код генерации списков:

```
public List<Car> GetCarsTypeOF(string carType)
{
    List<Car> cars;
    var db = new STOContext();

    if (carType == "LuxuryCar")
    {
        cars = db.Cars
            .Where(c => c.CarType
            .Equals(new LuxuryCar().GetType()))
            .ToList();
    }
    else if (carType == "MinivanCar")
    {
        cars = db.Cars
            .Where(c => c.CarType
            .Equals(new MinivanCar().GetType()))
            .ToList();
    }
    else if (carType == "SUV")
    {
        cars = db.Cars
            .Where(c => c.CarType
            .Equals(new SUV().GetType()))
            .ToList();
    }
    else if (carType == "SportCar")
    {
        cars = db.Cars
            .Where(c => c.CarType
            .Equals(new SportCar().GetType()))
            .ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    return cars;
}
```

*PS: если что то не так с оформлением вопроса или нужна еще информация - вопрос дополню*

Comment: зачем такое непотребство: `new LuxuryCar().GetType()`, если у тебя в строке уже приходит нужный тип и ты вполне можешь убрать все if и просто переданный параметр использовать

Comment: @Grundy мне же тип автомобиля приходит как строка, или есть какой то способ превратить текст строки в тип данных?

Comment: какого типа у тебя `c` в `.Where(c =>`? Добавь его описание в вопрос, чтобы было видно как поле `CarType` объявлено. В любом случае, даже если это `Type`, у него есть поле `Name`, в котором хранится имя типа в виде строки и ты вполне можешь сравнить это значение с переданной строкой.

Comment: @Grundy ох точно, у `CarType` же есть `Name`! Сейчас протестирую

Comment: @Grundy все работает, немного не так как надо, но это уже мой косяк, буду чинить. Большое спасибо!